# CS1061: 'PlayerInput' does not contain a definition for 'CharacterControls'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a character walk in unity but the error pops up that says  "error CS1061: 'PlayerInput' does not contain a definition for 'CharacterControls' and no accessible extension method 'CharacterControls' accepting a first argument of type 'PlayerInput' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I can't seem to find anything that can help, plus I'm really new to C#, so please bear with me.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static System.Numerics.Vector3;


class AnimationAndMovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerInput playerInput;
    CharacterController characterController;
    Animator animator;
 
    Vector2 currentMovementInput;
    Vector3 currentMovement;
    bool isMovementPressed;
    float rotationFactorPerFrame = 15.0f;

    public bool IsMovementPressed { get => isMovementPressed; set => isMovementPressed = value; }

    void Awake()
    {
        playerInput = new PlayerInput();
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        

        playerInput.CharacterControls.Move.started += onMovementInput;
        playerInput.CharacterControls.Move.canceled += onMovementInput;
        playerInput.CharacterControls.Move.performed += onMovementInput;
    }

    void handleRotation()
    {
        Vector3 posititonToLookAt;

        posititonToLookAt.z = currentMovement.z;
        posititonToLookAt.y = 0.0f;
        posititonToLookAt.x = currentMovement.x;

        Quaternion currentRotation = transform.rotation;

        if (IsMovementPressed)
        {
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(posititonToLookAt);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(currentRotation, targetRotation, rotationFactorPerFrame * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void onMovementInput (InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        currentMovementInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        currentMovement.x = currentMovementInput.x;
        currentMovement.z = currentMovementInput.y;
        IsMovementPressed = currentMovementInput.x != 0 || currentMovementInput.y != 0;
    }

    void handleAnimation()
    {
        bool isWalking = animator.GetBool("isWalking");

        if (IsMovementPressed &
            !isWalking)
        {
            animator.SetBool("isWalking", true);
        }

        else if (!IsMovementPressed & isWalking)
        {
            animator.SetBool("isWalking", false);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        handleRotation();
        handleAnimation();
        characterController.Move(currentMovement * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        playerInput.CharacterControls.Enable();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        playerInput.CharacterControls.Disable();
    }
}
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Simply said type `PlayerInput` doesnt have any method or other definition that is called `CharacterControls`. So you would have to investigate why this is the case. It might be the case that you are following a deprecated tutorial or you might have missed some steps.

Comment: Instead of PlayerInput, why not use Input.GetAxis?

Comment: @Displayname If the Input System is selected, `Input.GetAxis` will result in an error, unless “both” is selected, but that more often than not defeats the purpose, especially when it would seem that the tutorial was about the new Input System.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you were following a tutorial that was using the new "InputSystem". That means that your `PlayerInput` has been created for you, based on the details you used when creating your Input bindings. You have to go to your Actions window, which will look like ..

[image]

And from there, make sure that your action map is called exactly (spelling counts) "CharacterControls", and that it has a "Move" action, with as many move inputs as you want to include.

The fact that the IDE you are using (Microsoft Visual Studio?) didn't highlight this error before you even got back to the Unity editor makes me think your environment might not be set up correctly?

Comment: Why do you think the error wasn't highlighted in the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Click "Save Asset" in your PlayerInput window before generating the C# class.